# Spark/Yarn: Ramp up number of executors slowly over a period of time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark job to run on a cluster managed with Yarn (with dynamic allocation turned on). My job needs to process data by hitting a few company-internal REST APIs (this is not optional). The API team has told me that they can auto-scale to a large number of concurrent requests, but that they need some time to scale up. So they've requested that I limit the rate of increase in requests/sec generated by my Spark job.

Is there any simple way to tell Spark to "ramp up" the number of executors evenly over a predefined period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Spark Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#resource-allocation-policy), you can slow down the rate that new executors are requested with `spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.sustainedSchedulerBacklogTimeout`. This feels like a bit of a hack, though.

Comment: This, combined with `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` for an ultimate cap on parallelism, did the trick. However, as you say it's a bit hacky and you can't control the number of executors that get added after each timeout, which will always be double what was requested previously.